On macOS FileProviderExtension is it possible to forbid adding items to a folder but allow rename of existing items inside a folder?
On macOS FileProviderExtension there is a NSFileProviderItemCapabilities property on NSFileProviderItem. Possible capabilities are:

allowsReading
allowsWriting
allowsReparenting
allowsRenaming
allowsTrashing
allowsDeleting
allowsEvicting
allowsExcludingFromSync
allowsAddingSubItems
allowsContentEnumerating
allowsAll

My requirement is to not allow adding new files (or folders) to some parent folder, so I exclude the allowsAddingSubItems right on the parent folder. However, the problem is that now items inside that folder cannot be renamed even though all the child items have the allowsRenaming capability.
Is there a way to fix that? Should perhaps a bug be filed to Apple?
